# Estimate Fee returning -1

Tags: fee-estimation

I updated the bitcoin node to version to 140200 on top of which one of my applications was running. There wasn't any issue with the flow of the application `estimatefee` RPC I get -1 for no matter what I give as the number of blocks. Also the alternate fee api `estimatesmartfee` returns negative values. 
When I execute the same api on a node with version 140100 it gives me a positive result
How do I resolve this ?

Comment: Ref: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/83352/bch-estimatefee-return-1

Answer (score 4):

-1 means "not enough information for an accurate estimation".

Try with a higher confirmation target.

Comment: I also thought it returns -1 when the block target is out of range (limits = 2-20)

Comment: i tried all numbers till 250 block numbers. Still it did not work.

Comment: How long has your node been running?