# BCH - estimatefee return -1

Tags: transaction-fees, bitcoin-cash, fee-estimation

When I call estimatefee 1 in testnet it returns: -1

According to [docs](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#estimatefee):

> If the node doesn’t have enough information to make an estimate, the
>   value -1 will be returned

But on my `bitcoin-cli getblockchaininfo`, my `verificationprogress` is: `0.9999960537430175`

What am I missing?

Comment: Downvoter why? I already said that I know the reason? Pathetic!

Answer (score 1):

From the doc:

> -1 is always returned for nblocks == 1 as it is impossible to calculate a fee that is high enough to get reliably included in the next block

https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.16.0/rpc/util/estimatefee/

Comment: But my node is running quite long and my verificationprogress is: 0.9999960537430175

Comment: No, it means for "estimatefee N", N must be larger than one, or it'll return -1.

Comment: Of course I ran with N larger than one, but no matter what number I entered, I get the same returned result

Comment: Just get this error again after I restart my PC

Answer (score 0):

Seem that after I restart my PC then things worked!

Comment: I just get this error again and restart my PC doesn't work!